# Scripting git commands with Python

Tags: windows-server-2008, python, git

Is there any way to pass the username and password to a git command so I can script it through  Python? I understand the password will be in cleartext but for my application it is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH keys for authentication. It sounds like you might be on Windows, so you'll want to look into PuTTY's Pageant. More information on your situation would be helpful.